# Event Listener for Web Notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Is there a way to set an event listener for a desktop notification?

```
document.addEventListener("desktop notification", function(){
    // do something
});
```

I've looked through the [MDN event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), but the only event type for a notification seems to be only for `alert()`.

Comment: A desktop notification event may be emitted from a browser, but it's listened to by the window manager of the OS. The browser itself is not notified about these events.

Answer (score 9):

See https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier project for working sample. Notice snippet (source from https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier/blob/development/app/src/static/preload.js):

```
function setNotificationCallback(callback) {

    const OldNotify = window.Notification;
    const newNotify = (title, opt) => {
        callback(title, opt);
        return new OldNotify(title, opt);
    };
    newNotify.requestPermission = OldNotify.requestPermission.bind(OldNotify);
    Object.defineProperty(newNotify, 'permission', {
        get: () => {
            return OldNotify.permission;
        }
    });

    window.Notification = newNotify;
}
```

So, you replace window's Notification object with own object that act as a proxy with added behaviour (calling callback on creating new Notification).

Hope this helps

Comment: This helped me greatly, however, the catch is to call this as early as possible, before any Notification object gets created

Comment: @Tikiboy: glad to help. Sure, this code should be run as initialization step for app.

Comment: nativefier helped me loads. Cheers mate!

Comment: I'm trying to capture slack notifications using this. I put a console.log and I can see that the script is getting loaded, but I don't see any changes to the notifications. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm also trying to do this with Slack. @LeoReyes did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @supertrue I no longer have a need for capturing slack notifications, but I am for discord via websocket and last time I looked, I think you can do something similar for slack. If that might fit your need, I can give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

@marekful is right. Instead of placing global event listeners, you may consider placing a callback or even attach an event on the Notification object.

```
var noticeMe = new Notification(title, options); 
noticeMe.onshow = function() { console.log("easy!") };
```

A full list of supported events may be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification, Also [here](http://codepen.io/TheodoreVorillas/blog/notification-api) is an article I wrote a few months back about the Notification API

Take a look at

- [Notification.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclick)

  [Notification.onclose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclose)

  [Notification.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onerror)

  [Notification.onshow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onshow)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the usage of the callback but I'm actually intending to inject some javascript into a page to listen for such notifications I have no control over, and I'm not sure if there's some workaround I can use.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am also trying to catch all notifications, and have no control over the creation of the notification itself.

Comment: Also trying the same thing, catch notifications from other webapps. You guys found anything yet? @gauge