# Create Firefox Extension to Detect Push Notification Received from Any Site

Tags: firefox, push-notification, firefox-addon

I'd like to create a simple Firefox extension to write a simple message to the Javascript console when a push notification is received from any site.  I see there is a [notification show event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/show_event) that seems like it should work although I can't seem to find an example of it in use.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that that API would handle your use case because the event is not global. It is placed on the object e.g.

```
var notify = new Notification("Hi there!").addEventListener('show', e => console.log("We showed it! ", e));
```

I can't think of a better solution if you want to watch for global events than what is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36868084/4875295 -- Monkey Patching!

Copying the code from that answer for posterity:

```
function setNotificationCallback(callback) {

    const OldNotify = window.Notification;
    const newNotify = (title, opt) => {
        callback(title, opt);
        return new OldNotify(title, opt);
    };
    newNotify.requestPermission = OldNotify.requestPermission.bind(OldNotify);
    Object.defineProperty(newNotify, 'permission', {
        get: () => {
            return OldNotify.permission;
        }
    });

    window.Notification = newNotify;
}
```